# How to concatenate a class with a variable to get a static variable from this class?

Tags: flutter, dart, static

I am making a pokemon app and I have a question that I already had in other projects and I would like to know if anyone can help me with a solution.

I receive a variable called pokemonName from other screen, I want to pass the variable and concatenate with the class "Strings", it will be like Strings.+pokemonName.toLowerCase(), converting to lowercase to get the map from the class Strings, but I don't know how to achieve this to remove the switch and don't need to use a lot of cases for each pokemon.

```
class PokemonDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  final String pokemonName;
  final String image;
  Map<String, dynamic> pokemonMap = {};

  PokemonDetailScreen(this.pokemonName, this.image, this.index){

    getPokemonMap();

  }

     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();

  }

  void getPokemonMap(){

    switch(pokemonName){

      case "Bulbasaur":
        pokemonMap = Strings.bulbasaur;
            break;

      case "Charmander":
        pokemonMap = Strings.charmander; 
             break;

    }

  }

}

**Class in another dart file:**

class Strings {

 static Map bulbasaur = {};

}
```

**What I needed is something like this:**

```
void getPokemonMap(){

  pokemonMap = Strings.$pokemonMap.toLowerCase();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is have a static map indexed by the name of your Pokemons and whose values are maps.

```
class Strings {

  static Map<String, dynamic> map = {
    'Bulbasor': {},
    'Charmander': {},
    // ...
  };

}
```

And you’ll use it like this: `pokemonMap = Strings.map[pokemonName]`.

Comment: You are incredible :)

Answer (score 1):

~You can use JSON file to do all this things instead use a class.~

I recommend not use a static class to do that thing, instead you can just make a normal class and instantiate on another file, so when the class that you call your another class will be dispose when the parent was.

```
class PokemonStrings {

   Map bulbasaur = {your map here};

}
```

To call that in another file you need just do

```
PokemonString _pokemonString = PokemonString();
```

And call whatever you need in the class that you instantiate

```
var bulbasaurMap = _pokemonString.bulbasaur;
```

But even so you need walk with static class. Just call the name of class followed by dot to access all the static attributes

```
var bulbasaurMap = PokemonString.bulbasaur;
```